# What are some fields that require Stochastic?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

I am a Pure Maths PhD student researching in functional analysis, particularly Banach space theory,

Recently I came across stochastic control theory, which perform optimization using stochastic (uncertainty). ]
I am fascinated by the use Stochastic calculus on optimization, which I would never think about it if I never come across it.

I am interested to know how many fields would require stochastic knowledge.

Some fields that I know are Stochastic programming, mathematical finance (Black-Scholes equation).

Comment: Stochastic differential equations and machine learning.

Comment: @Wuestenfux machine learning uses stochasticity in so far as it uses optimization as far as I know.

Comment: Quantum stochastic calculus (quantum optics, quantum measurement theory) relies heavily on functional analysis.

Comment: Finance and economics use it a lot. It is not just Black-Scholes model. For example investment and capital structure decisions by firms have been studied a lot using stochastic control.

Comment: Study of integro-differential equations (via Markov processes)